# Recent and New not working in node-imap for outlook

Tags: node.js, email, office365, imap, node-imap

I am using node-imap to search for the latest emails in my Outlook account's inbox. The documentation mentions the use of the "recent" or "new" flag. However, it seems to work fine for Gmail but not for Outlook. I have attached my code below. Can someone please suggest a solution?

```
var Imap = require("imap"); // version :  "^0.8.19",

let config = {
  keepalive: {
    interval: 4000,
    idleInterval: 200000,
    forceNoop: true,
  },
  user: "example@outlook.com",
  password: "xxxxxxxxxxx", // app password
  host: "outlook.office365.com",
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
};

let imap = new Imap(config);

imap.connect()

imap.once("ready", function () {
  console.log("Email connection established!");

  imap.openBox("INBOX", false, function (err, box) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error opening inbox");
    }
  });
});

imap.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.on("close", function (err) {
  console.log("connection closed");
});

imap.on("end", function (err) {
  console.log("connection ended");
});

imap.on("mail", function (newMsgNums) {
  console.log(`${newMsgNums} mails received!`);

 imap.search(["RECENT"], function (error, results) {
    if (!results || results.length == 0) {
      console.log(`No recent email available!`);
      return;
    }

    var fetchQuery = imap.fetch(results, {
      bodies: [""],
      struct: true,
    });

    fetchQuery.on("message", function (msg, seqno) {
      msg.on("body", async function (stream, info) {
        console.log(stream);
      });
      msg.on("attributes", function (attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
      });
      msg.on("end", function () {});
    });

    fetchQuery.once("error", function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    fetchQuery.on("end", function () {});
  });
});
```

So here on mail event triggered when mails arrive , and i am searching recent mails on those mails.

Comment: Don't use RECENT, it's flaky. Its condition for being recent was never good, and in the modern world is bad. Something like UNSEEN will likely match your expectations better.

Comment: My problem statement is to filter out most recent mails both Seen and Unseen mails.

Comment: Well, RECENT definitely won't help with that: A message loses the \recent pseudoflag as soon as anyone has had an opportunity to read it, even without making use of the opportunity. Try a date-based search such as SINCE.